# Deleting multiple elements of array

Tags: php, arrays

i try to delete the repeated array, based on publishedDate and name, because i need only one person for published date.

```
^ array:3 [▼
  0 => array:16 [▼
    "name" => "Peter San"
    "publishedDate" => 1661378400
  ]
  1 => array:16 [▼
    "name" => "Peter San"
    "publishedDate" => 1661378400
  ]
  2 => array:16 [▼
    "name" => "Mike Tomas"
    "publishedDate" => 1661292000
  ]
]
```

i try with this code, but with this only delete the array based on publishedDate:

```
        $ids = array_column($resultOfAthors, 'publishedDate');
        $ids = array_unique($ids);
        $resultOfAthors = array_filter($resultOfAthors, function ($key, $value) use ($ids) {
            return in_array($value, array_keys($ids));
        }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

I need delete the name and the publishedDate in the same time

Answer (score 0):

To delete your subarray if it has name "Peter San" and publishedDate 1661378400, you can do it as follows:

```
foreach($aray as $row){
    if($row["name"] == "Peter San" && $row["publishedDate"] == 1661378400){
        unset($row);
    }
}
```